# Rails show posts from only users that the current user is following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and having a go at a twitter type web app.

The 'following' and 'followers' part of the app is fine. However I want to filter the Posts index to only show posts that the current user is following.

I need to do something along the lines of:

```
@posts = Post.where('user_id LIKE ?', current_user.friendships  )
```

As I expected this throws up an error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (user_id LIKE 8,9)
```

It seems close to what I want because 8,9 are the id's of the friends I am following.

Any suggestions as to the best way to get what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as an update TK-421's answer was correct in relation to my question. But my question was slightly flawed. If the friendship is destroyed it creates a problem. Better to use @posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.friends).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `IN` instead of `LIKE`:

```
@posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.friendships)
```

Or:

```
@posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.friendships)
```